# Install pip on Ubuntu server 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-server

I just can't figure out how to get `pip3` working on Ubuntu Server.

I've done:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

When running `sudo python3 --version` the output is `3.6.6`.

I've tried the following:

`sudo apt-get install python3-pip` and `python3-pip3`, `python-pip3`, i've tried installing `python3-setuptools` and they appear to be installed but `easy_install` is not recognised as a command.

I think i've literally tried all options and the error `unable to locate package python3-pip` pops every time.

Comment: I think I had that too once; I think there is some head-scratching going on between the `dist-packages` and `site-packages` directories.  Check you Python path setting for packages and/or set it explicitly.  There was a reason for why it is the way it is but I no longer recall what that was..

Comment: After installing with # apt install python3-pip Are you attempting to run pip from the command line as: $ pip3 or $ python3 -m pip ?

Comment: @Mark i tried everything like: `sudo python3 pip install virtualenv` or `sudo pip`, `sudo pip3`, including the solution with `-m`. I dont get past apt install python3-pip because i get `unable to locate pack

Comment: the Ubuntu package for pip is called `python3-pip` to install it, you need to run `sudo apt install python3-pip` you then should be able run pip with `python3 -m pip install ...` can you say which error messages you are getting when any of these steps fail?

Comment: In case it helps: in my case this was solved by adding "universe" to apt sources (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1061488/865083))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I personally install pip, instead of worrying about the headache of finding it on various package managers.

```
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

Then use pip from python3 like so:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install <packagename>
```

Comment: I bow to you, thank you! It did work, yes.

Comment: I tried this and it fails with this error on a fresh Ubuntu 18 LTS: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'`